# How to take field seperator as blank line and record seperator and double blank line with awk

Tags: awk

I want to take field separator as blank line and record separator as double blank line in awk to extract the first and third field of a text file, which is as:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am

Lorem1

asdds f fgb g

Lorem ipsum1 

dsfdff

2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am

Lorem2

dfdg g gh hf

Lorem ipsum2 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

So that I get as a result:

```
lorem1    Lorem ipsum1 
lorem2    Lorem ipsum2
```

Comment: If you have any control over whatever generates that file, using blank lines to separate records and linebreaks to separate fields is directly supported (at least by GNU awk): https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am

Lorem1

asdds f fgb g

Lorem ipsum1

dsfdff


2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am

Lorem2

dfdg g gh hf

Lorem ipsum2

Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

Then your awk would look like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n\n"; FS="\n\n"}{print $2,$4}' yourfile.txt
Lorem1 Lorem ipsum1
Lorem2 Lorem ipsum2
```

Comment: I simplified my text and reduced its content to be suitable to put in this website. But my real text is made up of paragraphs of multi-line that each separates with a blank line and also each record is also separated with double blank line.

Comment: I think this will do the trick then. The Field Separator here is two line feed characters `/n` which is, essentially, a blank line. The Record Separator is three line feed characters (double blank line). So this should work.

Comment: I know this works for this example. But what if we have a text that instead of one line separated with blank line, we would have 2 or 3 lines separated by blank line. By the way, thanks for your answer. Here is a link to my file http://updap.com/74c/pubmed_result.txt

Comment: Those 2 or 3 lines would be treated as a single field since it would take two line breaks to move to the next field. Is that what you want? Essentially each paragraph is a single field, multiple paragraphs separated by a single blank line would be part of the same "row" and two blank lines would signify a new row.

Comment: I want to extract background and author section of the file in the link for each record

Comment: For that file and "Author" and "Background" section (also printing with a blank line between fields and double blank line between records): `awk 'BEGIN{ORS==RS="\n\n\n"; OFS=FS="\n\n"}{print $4,$5}' pubmed_result.txt`

Comment: If you wish to get very surgical and only extract if it starts with "Author information" or "Background" you could do: `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n"; OFS=FS=":"}($1=="Author information"||$1=="Background"){print $0}' pubmed_result.txt`